# How to do multiple mysql queries in one line in Node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to get results from multiple tables with one request from client. I first tried JOIN, but that would mean I'd have to have multiple rows that contain duplicate information. Then I decided to do a different query for each table separately, although I'm not sure know how cost efficient this is.

How should I construct the query so that it is accepted by Node.js? The one I'm trying to use now doesn't work if I don't use quotation marks to wrap the whole query, but if I do use them it complains there is an error with my query.

Here is the code for the query.

```
sql = "'SELECT * from `Ilmoittautuminen` WHERE `optunnus` LIKE ' + mysql.escape(reg.body.optunnus); 'SELECT * from `Jasenmaksu` WHERE `optunnus` LIKE ' + mysql.escape(reg.body.optunnus); 'SELECT * from `OppOikeus` WHERE `optunnus` LIKE ' + mysql.escape(reg.body.optunnus);"
console.log(sql);
connection.query(sql, function(err, rows){
    console.log(rows)
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.json({
            success: false,
            message: err,
        });
    }else{
         queryResponse(res, rows);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

taking reference of https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql
passs **multipleStatements:true** in your connection param
and try with an exmaple

```
conn.query(`
SELECT * FROM posts limit 1;
SELECT * FROM Users limit 1;
`, (err, results)=>{
   console.log(err, results)
});
```